# How to plot one columns "usage" of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot one variable as a constant, total_cap, in this case and layer on the maxused_capacity and meanused_capacity values.  Essentially I would like the visual of a stacked bar plot but I do not want the totals agg'd together, the height of the bar for each site should awlays be just the value of Total_Cap with the other two values layered on

example df:

```
SITE    Total_Cap   maxused_Cap meanused_Cap
 A         4            3            2
 B         8            7            4
 C         12           11           5
 D         16           13           10
```

I tried this code but it simply adds the values together when plotting the bar

```
x= df4[['SITE','maxused_cap','Total_Cap']]
y= x.set_index('SITE')
z=y.groupby('SITE')
z.plot.bar(stacked=True).mean()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this does what you want to achieve by scaling the values relative to `Total_Cap`

```
df.set_index('SITE', inplace=True)
df[['maxused_Cap','meanused_Cap']].div(
    (df['maxused_Cap']+df['meanused_Cap'])/df['Total_Cap'],
    axis=0).plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(8,6));
```

Out:

[image: stacked with caped height]

---

Setup the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''
SITE    Total_Cap   maxused_Cap meanused_Cap
 A         4            3            2
 B         8            7            4
 C         12           11           5
 D         16           13           10'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df
```

Out:

```
  SITE  Total_Cap  maxused_Cap  meanused_Cap
0    A          4            3             2
1    B          8            7             4
2    C         12           11             5
3    D         16           13            10
```

Comment: thanks @Michael Szczesny, how would I tweak your code to show only one column relative to the total capacity?  Say I want to show only maxused relative to total capacity.

Comment: That would be `Total_Cap` labeled `maxused_Cap`. Just rename the column and plot it?

Comment: @Michael...I want to show the site capacity bar and then a layered on sub-bar showing its relative max used value.  I dont thing renaming the Total_cap column achieves that unless I am not understanding your reply.

Comment: So the heights would be `3/4, 7/8, 11/12, 13/16`?

Comment: correct for this example, but my real dataset contains many more sites then four and depending when data is refershed, the values per site could change

Comment: `(df.maxused_Cap / df.Total_Cap).plot.bar()`